# iframe rendering localhost again instead of the website i'm passing in from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component passing the website URL to the the Mockup component as a prop:

```
if (pageContent === 'mockup') {
        return <Mockup currentSite={currentSite} />;
}
```

Mockup component:

```
const Mockup = ({ currentSite }) => {
    // const [currentMockup, setCurrentMockup] = useState('desktop');

    let mockupType;
    if (currentMockup === 'desktop') {
        mockupType = <Desktop site={currentSite} />;
    } else if (currentMockup === 'mobile') {
        mockupType = <Mobile site={currentSite} />;
    } else if (currentMockup === 'tablet') {
        mockupType = <Tablet site={currentSite} />;
    }

    return mockupType;
};

export default Mockup;
```

When I `console.log(currentSite)` it's the value i'm looking for. Here's the iframe component:

```
import './Desktop.css';
import desktopMockup from '../../assets/desktop.png';

const Desktop = site => {

console.log(currentSite); // correct value is returned

    return (
        <div className="desktop">
            <iframe src={site} scrolling="no" title="desktop"></iframe>
            <img src={desktopMockup} alt="desktop mockup" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Desktop;
```

So when the `currentSite` prop makes it way to the Desktop component, it's the right value. If I hard code the website in, it works, but when I pass it in as an argument, it re-renders localhost.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ruled out caching?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: I meant, was the localhost value being cached by the browser, but it looks like that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I forgot to destructure `site` when receiving it as a prop on my Desktop component